# Cannot apply backdrop blur to navbar dropdown in chromium browsers

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isResourceOpen, setIsResourceOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
  };

  const handleResourceClick = () => {
    setIsResourceOpen(!isResourceOpen);
  };


  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <header className="fixed bg-violet/50 w-screen isolate z-10 mx-auto shadow-lg backdrop-blur-lg">
        <nav
          className={`flex w-screen flex-row
          }`}
        >

          <div
            className={`lg:flex ${
              cabinetBold.className
            } lg:flex-row lg:items-between mt-4 lg:gap-10`}
          >
            <Link
              href="/schedule"
              className="hover:text-secondary block lg:inline-block "
            >
              NAV ITEM 1
            </Link>

            <div className="flex flex-col" ref={resourceRef}>
              <span
                className=" hover:text-secondary block lg:inline-block cursor-pointer "
                onClick={handleResourceClick}
              >
                NAV ITEM 2
              </span>
            
             <div className=
{`${isResourceOpen ? "opacity-1" : "opacity-0 duration-500"} 
fixed bg-violet/50  backdrop-blur-md ${cabinetMedium.className} shadow-lg transition-all ease-in-out duration-500 z-20 text-white invisible lg:visible top-20`}
              >

                <ul className="w-[18.6rem] mt-0.5 text-left list-none">
                  <li>DROPDOWN ITEM 1</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
  
            </div>
          </div>

          
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};
```

basically I'm trying to achieve a glassmorphic navbar, so a backdrop filter on the navbar and also on the dropdown. Right now, When i apply backdrop to the dropdown it won't work on Chromium browsers. It works perfectly fine on firefox.

After some research I've found out that backdrop filters in chromium browers only work on their parent divs, while in firefox the filter works on the root.

Comment: I've included dropdown functionality for NAV ITEM 2 only